# Wait for nested sub-promises

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I am trying to implement a front-end for a web-application API.
There are three Ajax-Calls need to be made.

1. List all groups.
2. For each group list its members.
3. From each group's members get the `terminals` and expand the value.

The three Ajax calls look like this:

```
  function getGroups () {
    return jQuery.ajax({
      url: "https://webapp.mydomain.com/group?session=" + his.getSessionToken() + "&customer=test"
    });
  }

  function getMembers (group) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
      url: "https://webapp.mydomain.com/group/" + group.id + "/member?session=" + his.getSessionToken() + "&customer=test"
    });
  }

  function getTerminal (terminal) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
      url: "https://webapp.mydomain.com/terminal/" + terminal.tid + "?session=" + his.getSessionToken() + "&customer=test"
    });
  }
```

I also have the following miscellaneous functions:

```
  function display (html) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
  }

  function success (message) {
    display('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(message, null, 2));
  }

  function error (error) {
    display('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
  }
```

Now I face the problem how to chain the respective Promises (actually `Deferred`s) correctly.

I tried the following:

```
  function setTerminal (terminals, index) {
    function curry (terminal) {
      terminals[i] = terminal;
    }

    return curry;
  }

  function expandMembers (members) {
    var promises = [];
    var promise;
    var terminals = members.terminal || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < terminals.length; i++) {
      promise = getTerminal(terminals[i]);
      promise.then(setTerminal(terminals, i));
      promises.push(promise);
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
  }

  function getMembers (groups) {
    var promises = [];
    var promise;

    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
      console.log('Group #' + i + ': ' + JSON.stringify(groups[i]));
      promise = getMembers(groups[i]);
      promise.then(expandMembers);
      promises.push(promise);
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
  }

  function listGroups (groups) {
    getGroups().then(getMembers).then(success);
  }
```

This will however not wait for the sub-promises (and actually return a list of empty lists, one for each group).

What I want to achieve is:

1. Get all groups (`getGroups`).
2. For each group get all members (`getMembers`).
3. Set members on group object.
4. For each terminal in the group members, get the verbose terminal information (`getTerminal`).
5. Replace brief terminal information with verbose terminal information.
6. If all above is done, display the groups JSON list.

I am at a loss.

Comment: As for the solution. I'm no expert on promises in JavaScript (by far even), but based on experience with similar constructs in other languages, I think the sub-promises should [`await` the result of the promises they rely on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), and the only promise you return is the toplevel one. That promise will only be done/fulfilled when all the sub ones are done, because it awaits them. The awaiting should happen in the background too, so your main script is not blocked by it, unless you also decide to await the main one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then()` returns a new Promise that resolves when the passed function returns. So if I understood your question correctly, this is what you'll probably want to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < terminals.length; i++) {
  promise = getTerminal(terminals[i]);
  promises.push(promise.then(setTerminal(terminals, i)));
}

return Promise.all(promises);
```

(applied to all your Promise groups)

Comment: Yes. This solved my problem. Additionally, I initialized the promises array with the `groups` variable, so that the first value of the result array will be the groups array.